# ListBox and Label will not gradually display the numbers going through the loop

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to show the numbers of 2 dice on each roll.
When I run the program
*lblDice1* and *lblDice2*  will only show the numbers of the last roll and listBox *lstResults* will only display after the for loop ends. How do I gradually show the result of each roll.
Here is my code

```
private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
        {
            Dice1 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            Dice2 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            lblDice1.Text = Convert.ToString(Dice1);
            lblDice2.Text = Convert.ToString(Dice2);
            strOut = Convert.ToString(Dice1);
            strOut2 = Convert.ToString(Dice2);
            lblRollNum.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
            if (Dice1 == Dice2)
                lstResults.Items.Add(i + "\t" + strOut + "\t" + strOut2 + "\t" + "Same Dice Value");
            else
                lstResults.Items.Add(i + "\t" + strOut + "\t" + strOut2);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
}
```

Comment: If WinForms, you could use a **Timer** and its `Tick` event to roll the dice instead of a `for` loop.  For a quick hack solution, though, place a call to `Application.DoEvents();` before your `Sleep` line.  This is definitely not the "proper" way to go about it though...

Comment: Thanks that worked but I see what you mean the Timer is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

What type of app are you using, WinForm or WPF?

If you are WPF, your loop will be tying up the UI thread so the UI will not render until the loop has finished.

You could use something like MVVM, http://galasoft.ch/, to bind the UI to the changing data in your model.